# Redis Cluster Issue

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have setup a redis cluster with three master nodes with version `5.0.6`

One of the node went down all of a sudden because of load test. The node came back up fine but I started observing a different type of issue in redis insight which I have attached an image of

Also in redis insight logs I observe this

```
redisinsight All nodes cached in the StrictRedisCluster object don't agree. Invalidating cached connection
```

[image: Image is attached here]